# How to check if the datatype of an object value is null (JS)

Tags: javascript

Some values of my object are sometimes not in the domain and thus have a null value. How can I filter out the null values from this object when trying to iterate through it?

That's the code I wrote but it doesnt do anything.

```
function enLanguage(){
    let value1 = Object.values(dicEnglish);
    let key1 = Object.keys(dicEnglish);
    for (let y=0; y<50; y++){
      if ((typeof key1[y] === "object") || (typeof value1[y] ==="object")){
        continue;
      }else{
        let text1 = value1[y];
        document.getElementById(key1[y]).textContent = text1;
        key1[y].textContent=value1[y]}}}
```

Comment: `(typeof key1[y] === "object")` is pointless, object keys are always strings. And this piece of code: `key1[y].textContent=value1[y]` strings can't be mutated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple points to notice:

1. In JS an object key cannot be another object.
   So this `typeof key1[y] === "object"` is not going to work.
2. You would probably want `Object.entries` function, example:

```
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(dicEnglish)) {
    // Do something
}
```

3. To check if a value is nullish you can use `value == null` (note 2 equal signs).
   This returns true if a value is null or undefined.

Given said, you can rewrite your function as:

```
function enLanguage(){
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(dicEnglish)) {
        // Here you check for null
        if (value == null) {
            // Do something
        } else {
            // Do something else
        }
        
    }
```

Comment: Did this and it raises an error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'textContent') and this is the function:                                                                           function enLanguage(){
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(dicEnglish)){
      if (value == null){
        continue;
      }else{
        let text = value;
        document.getElementById(key).textContent = text;
        key.textContent=value}}}

Comment: The `document.getElementById(key)` returned `null` thus you couldn't set its `textContent` property. Make sure it exists on your page. Also no need to declare the `text` variable, you can just use `value`

Answer (score 0):

strangely enough, the `null` datatype in JavaScript is also an object.
but we can filter it out through the `!` operator.

for example:

```js
console.log(!null) // true
console.log(!undefined) // true

const x = "Hello World!"
console.log(!x) // false
```

it returns true if the subsequent value is `null`, `undefined` or `0` (falsy values)

so in your code change the condition:

```js
if (!key1[y] || !value1[y]) continue
```

this will now skip any [`falsy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) values

Answer (score 0):

A compact way to check if a value is `null` is trwar using strict equality operators:

```
(value === null)  // true if value is of datatype NULL
(value !== null)  // true if value is not of datatype NULL
```

Non-strict operators provide a similar test but check if a value is `null` or `undefined`:

```
(value == null)  // true if value is of datatype NULL or UNDEFINED
(value != null)  // true if value is not of datatype NULL or UNDEFINED.
```

where "NULL" mean the data type of `null` and "UNDEFINED" means the data type of `undefined`.

The `typeof` operator returns "function" for function objects (of data type OBJECT) and "object" for the `null` primitive of type NULL. This dates back to the original design and implementation of JavaScript on PC's of the 1990s era, and is so entrenched it can't be changed.

**TL;DR** That `typeof null` returns "object" does not mean `null` is an object or has data type OBJECT. `null` is the singleton value of JavaScript data type NULL.